# Get Checked Rows[Selected Rows] from kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Here is My grid, When Checkbox is Selected I want to pass the CheckBox Checked/Not Checked Value to Controller. When accessing in the controller model is not persisting the Checkbox value. Can you please guide me acheiving it.

My View :

```
@using(@Html.BeginForm("RequisitionApply", "Requisition", FormMethod.Post, new               {           approvalReason = Model, @id = "addExpenseItem" }))
{
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ZCW.MVC.ViewModels.ManagerRequisitionSearchListViewModel>()
                 .Name("ManagerRequisitionApprovalGrid")
                  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .Events(e => e.RequestEnd("GetPaginationDisplay"))
                                    .PageSize(25)
                                                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetDetails", "List").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
                      //.Update(update => update.Action("Apply", "List").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
                                    .ServerOperation(true)
                                    )
                             .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            //RequistionName(ID)
                            columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName).ClientTemplate("#=FirstName#<a href='" + Url.Action("GetResource", "List", new { NameID = "#=NameID#"}) + "'>(#=NameID#) </a>").Title(@Html.LocalizedText("ID")).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "alignleft" });

                            //Location
                            columns.Bound(p => p.Location)
                                    .Title(@Html.LocalizedText("Location")).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "alignleft" });


                            // Accept Header
                              columns.Template(p => p.Accept).Title("")
                                .HeaderTemplate("<i class='icon-ok gicn tooltips' data-original-title='Approve' data-placement='top'></i><br><div class='checker'><span><input id='selectallApprove' class='chkboxApprove' type='checkbox' onclick='ToggleChkBoxApprove(this.checked);' #= Accept ?  checked='checked' : '' # /></span></div>")
                                 .ClientTemplate("<span>  <input id='checkbox' onclick='grdChkBoxClick(this); ' class='chkboxApprove' type='checkbox' name='remember' /></span>")
                                   .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "aligncenter" })
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "textaligncenter" });


                            //Decline Header
                            columns.Template(p => p.Decline).Title("")
                               .HeaderTemplate("<i class='icon-remove ricn tooltips' data-original-title='Decline' data-placement='top'></i><br><div class='checker'><span> <input id='selectallDecline'   class='chkboxDecline' type='checkbox' onclick='ToggleChkBoxDecline(this.checked);' #= Decline ?  checked='checked' : '' # /></span></div>")
                                .ClientTemplate("<span>  <input id='checkbox1' onclick='grdChkBoxClick(this); ' class='chkboxDecline' type='checkbox' name='remember'/></span>")
                                  .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "aligncenter" })
                               .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "textaligncenter" });
                        })
                                                                             .AutoBind(true)
                                                                                    .Sortable()
                                                                                    .EnableCustomBinding(true)
                    )

     <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="submit" id="Apply" class="submitbtn" style="border: 0px none;"><i class="greenbtn"></i>@GlobalResourceHelper.GetGlobalResource(ResourceFiles.ButtonsResources, "BTN_APPLY")</button>
                        </div>
}
```

MyController :

```
 public ActionResult Apply(ResourceViewModel ApprovalList)
 {
     // I'm not getting Checkbox Checked or not in ApprovalList
  }
```

Comment: Your checkboxes don't even have name attributes so they wont post back (and its invalid html because of the duplicate id's)

Comment: @Stephen I have Changed the Ids and added a name attribute then also value is not retaining and I have edited my code

Comment: are you posting via ajax ?

Comment: Your html is still invalid (each row has a checkbox with `id=checkbox` ) so get rid of the id's. Now you have a whole lot of checkboxes with `name="remember"` which have no relation to `ResourceViewModel` (you could check `Request.Form` to see whats posted back) but since unchecked checkboxes do not post back, there is no way to match up which row has been 'checked' or not.

Comment: @Ankush : No I'm not using Ajax

Comment: @stephen : Can you please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

You have to do this.

```
columns.Bound(x => x.IsChecked).ClientTemplate(
"<input name='IsChecked' class='chkBox' type='checkbox' 
  data-bind='checked: IsChecked' #= IsChecked ? checked='checked' : '' #/>");

        //check document ready 
    var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.tbody.on("change", ".chkBox", function (e) {

            var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
            var item = grid.dataItem(row);                
            //item.set("IsChecked", $(e.target).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0);
            kendo.bind(this,item);//this line or above line will handle this
        });
```

Post the Grid using an ajax call and send the Grid's data.

```
   var gridData = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
       //AJAX etc...
        data: JSON.stringify(gridData.dataSource.view()),
```